# Calling a php function after onclick event

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need help.

This PHP code shows me a table with the names of people from MySQL database:

```
if ($numRows>=1)
{
echo<<<END
<td align="center" bgcolor="e5e5e5">nazwisko</td>
</tr><tr>
END;
}
for ($i = 1; $i <= $numRows; $i++)
{
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
$nazwisko = $row['nazwisko'];   

echo<<<END
<td align="center">$nazwisko</td>
</tr><tr>
END;

}
```

I want this table showed only after click on button. HTML code looks something like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="index.php">
<input id="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Szukaj" class="btn btn-info">
```

My efforts were in vain. I will be grateful for help.

Comment: This is PHP/MySQL 101. I'd bet there are thousands of tutorials online for this.

Comment: You can't call a PHP function from JavaScript directly. You need to use Ajax between them.

Answer (score 0):

Your browser can't interpret PHP. You'll have to make an Ajax call.

```
request = $.ajax({
    url: "/index.php",
    type: "post"
});

request.done(function (response){
    // append the html somewhere on your page
});
```

Answer (score 0):

full code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>

        function phprun(){
         $.ajax({
                    url:'/index.php',
                    type:'post',
                    dataType:'html',
                    success:function(data){
                        $('#htmlshow').append(data);
                    },
 error:function(request,status,error){


$('#htmlshow').append("code:"+request.status+"\n"+"message:"+request.responseText+"\n"+"error:"+error);}

                })
        }
            </script>
        <div id="htmlshow">
        </div>
            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="/index.php" onsubmit="return false;">
            <input id="button" name="submit" type="submit" value="Szukaj" class="btn btn-info"     onclick='phprun()'>
```